# Citus upgrade failed

Tags: postgresql, psql, citus

I am running citus in kubernetes and trying to do an upgrade from 10.2 to 11.2, the underneath postgres version is 14.

Image used in deployment for upgrade: **citusdata/citus:11.2-pg14**

After performing the upgrade with image **citus:11.2-pg14** , pod goes in to **crashloopbackoff** state with following error:

`ERROR:  loaded Citus library version differs from installed extension version`
`Loaded library requires 11.2, but the installed extension version is 10.2-4`
`HINT:  Run ALTER EXTENSION citus UPDATE and try again.`

I cannot execute the ALTER EXTENSION citus UPDATE as the pod is in crahsed state.

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in general Citus does not provide docker images for production use, they have the following quote in the docs `The Docker image is intended for development/testing purposes only, and has not been prepared for production use.`

So, that's probably why upgrades are not part of the story.

Still, one workaround might be to do `SET citus.enable_version_checks TO off;` and try the `alter extension command`

Comment: yes, I was able to perform alter extension command after disabling version checks however new errors do appear as we do not have a proper way to restart the database